# How is the slideshow in demo ipads made?

Tags: ipad

If you look at a demo iPad in a store, there are autorunning slideshows displaying different features in the iPad and I wonder what program it is made with?

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to use somebody else's app, you could use something as simple as [Keynote for iOS](http://www.apple.com/ios/keynote/).

Or, you could write your own app that involves push segues pushing view controllers through a sequence and then popping back to the top view controller.  And touching various parts of a view controller could segue to different view controllers (e.g. using a UIButton connected to a segue).

In both of these cases, you'd need to physically restrict access to the home button if you want to keep the user from stopping the slide show.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I dont want to write my own app, just wanted to know if somebody knows how its done in the demos that you see in the stores. Restricting it to only show the opened slideshow is easily done in the parent settings.

Comment: Well since you're talking about the Apple store demo app, the only people that would know precisely are the Apple engineers & hard-working interns who have the Xcode project on their machines.  You can approximate a lot of this functionality by using Keynote.

Comment: Ok, I guess I have to take a look at Keynotes. Thanks.